# Cordova: google maps v3 not showing on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, google-maps

I am building a cordova app and i am stuck with a problem since three days.. I tried every thing i found on Stack or Google. My point is I can show a google map on android but not on iOS. There is just a grey div. On debug, when clicking on this div, I get this error : *TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.x')*

Another thing : I have a Gif loader that stay over the grey div, and it should go under the map div.

I am using gmap v3 with or without API key : same issue.
I copy my config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="co.brandyapp.applitest8" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>applitest8</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*.google.com" />
<access origin="*.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="*.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="*.brandyapp.co" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.google.com" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.googleapis.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.gstatic.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.brandyapp.co/*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
</widget>
```

The strange thing is I get the same issue with this tuto : *http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-google-maps/*

**Thank you for your help** ! This issue is driving me crazy ! :)